# Setup/Teardown Not Called In Unity Test Runner & Test Is Blocked

Tags: c#, unit-testing, unity-game-engine, test-runner

I've googled around and I don't see anyone else having this issue so maybe it's just me.

I setup a Unity Test Runner with a Playmode unit test suite.

However, if I try to run tests which have a [Setup] or [Teardown] in the suit, the tests don't run at all (after clicking Run of course). I just get a grey circle and no log. It literally doesn't run.

If I remove the attributes and call the methods manually, everything works.

Do you have any suggestions why the [Setup]/[Teardown] attributes are causing this odd behaviour?

Here is some example code that works and has passing/running tests:

```
public class PlayModeUnitTests
{
    Game game;

    void Setup()
    {
        GameObject gameGameObject = MonoBehaviour.Instantiate(Resources.Load<GameObject>("Prefabs/Game"));
        game = gameGameObject.GetComponent<Game>();
    }

    void Teardown()
    {
        Object.Destroy(game.gameObject);
    }

    [UnityTest]
    public IEnumerator MoveDown()
    {
        Setup();
        GameObject obj = game.SpawnObj();
        float initialYPos = obj.transform.position.y;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);

        Assert.Less(obj.transform.position.y, initialYPos);
    }
}
```

And here is sample code which causes the tests not to actually run and not even give an error message:

```
 public class PlayModeUnitTests
    {
        Game game;
        [SetUp]
        void Setup()
        {
            GameObject gameGameObject = MonoBehaviour.Instantiate(Resources.Load<GameObject>("Prefabs/Game"));
            game = gameGameObject.GetComponent<Game>();
        }

        [TearDown]
        void Teardown()
        {
            Object.Destroy(game.gameObject);
        }

        [UnityTest]
        public IEnumerator MoveDown()
        {
            GameObject obj = game.SpawnObj();
            float initialYPos = obj.transform.position.y;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);

            Assert.Less(obj.transform.position.y, initialYPos);
        }
    }
```

As you can see, the green checkmark on the .dll shows the tests were run but then none of the actual tests in the suite passed or failed:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They needed to be public, the error just was not clear

Answer (score 1):

My issue was that when using `[UnityTest]` the teardown must have the following:

- be `[UnityTeardown]`
- be `public`
- return `IEnumerator`

```cs
[UnityTearDown]
public IEnumerator Teardown()
{
  service.Dispose();
  yield return null;
}
```